# Displaying specific records in a queryset from within Django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-queryset

Is it possible to access a specific record of a QuerySet based on a value in one of its fields -- from within the template?

Let's say I have the following models:

```
Parent:
    someField

Child:
    parentFK = ForeignKey(Parent)
    bar = CharField
```

If `Parent` has many children, and I pass the QuerySet of `Parent.objects.all()` to my template, is it possible to access something like: `Parent.someField.bar where foo=4`?

In otherwords, access and display the field `bar` for the record where `foo` holds the value `4`? I only want to pass the `Parent` QuerySet to the template.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using custom template tag.
P.S. Is your model description correct? If you have Parent with many children is it ok, that parent contains a link to child, not vice-versa?

Comment: I realised my error after posting -- I'm about to change the model.

Comment: Hmm... nothing built into Django will do this?